# MessageConsumer.receive() hangs on ioexception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jms

Using jboss 5.1, java standalone application.

I am trying to listen to messages from standalone application to jboss jms.

Problem is when I kill the jboss server I am getting an exception in the standalone application side but the receive() still hangs therefor my thread is stuck and i am not able to reconnect or do anything else.

thats the exception in my standalone:

```
2012-05-31 11:47:18,738 org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker [ERROR] Got marshalling exception, exiting
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.jms.wireformat.SerializedPacket.write(SerializedPacket.java:81)
    at org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat.write(JMSWireFormat.java:237)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.versionedWrite(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:971)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:606)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketClientInvoker.transport(BisocketClientInvoker.java:418)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:122)
    at org.jboss.remoting.ConnectionValidator.doCheckConnectionWithLease(ConnectionValidator.java:522)
    at org.jboss.remoting.ConnectionValidator.run(ConnectionValidator.java:301)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

my standalone application code:

```
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MomTopicListenerAbs.class);
    protected String componentCode = null;
    protected int reconnectTimeInterval = 30000;
    MessageConsumer topicMsgConsumer = null;
    Session topicSession = null;
    String momUrl = null;
    Connection topicConnection = null;
    InitialContext jmsContext = null;
    private Thread listenerThread = null;
    boolean shouldListen = true;


@Override
    public void connectToTopic() throws Exception
    {
        TopicConnectionFactory myConnFactory;
        Topic myTopic;
        String MYCF_LOOKUP_NAME = MomConstants.MOM_EXTERNAL_CONNECTION_FACTORY;
        String MYTOPIC_LOOKUP_NAME = MomConstants.DISPATCHER_TOPIC_LOOKUP;
        jmsContext = new InitialContext();
        jmsContext.addToEnvironment("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        jmsContext.addToEnvironment("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jnp.interfaces");
        jmsContext.addToEnvironment(Context.PROVIDER_URL, momUrl);
        myConnFactory = (javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory) jmsContext.lookup(MYCF_LOOKUP_NAME);
        myTopic = (Topic) jmsContext.lookup(MYTOPIC_LOOKUP_NAME);
        topicConnection = myConnFactory.createConnection();
        topicSession = topicConnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        topicMsgConsumer = topicSession.createConsumer(myTopic);
        topicConnection.start();
    }

@Override
    public void run()
    {
        Message msg = null;
        log.info("Listening to Mom Topic at url=" + momUrl + " started.");
        try
        {

            connectToTopic();
            while (shouldListen)
            {
                try
                {       //this is where it hangs when I kill the jboss  server.
                    msg = topicMsgConsumer.receive();
                    if (msg == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Received empty msg from Topic Listener. could be caused by stopListening() invoke");
                    }
                    executeMsgThread(msg);
                }
                catch (JMSException e)
                {
                    log.error("Caught JMS exception, reconnecting...", e);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    log.error("Error in topic Listener. errorMsg=" + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            log.error(TAG + ", System error", t);
        }
```

How will I be able to catch that exception?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#setExceptionListener%28javax.jms.ExceptionListener%29) an [ExceptionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/ExceptionListener.html) on the connection in the client. When the server stops, you will get a callback from your registered listener.

**====== Update ======**

It's odd that you are not getting a callback from the exception listener. To avoid the stalling thread, you might consider using the [time out version of receive](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receive%28long%29) or [set a message listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#setMessageListener%28javax.jms.MessageListener%29). That way you will not be in perma-block.

Comment: How long do you wait before you kill your client app? Typically when the server is killed, the sockets it has opened will also be closed. Client applications detect the socket closure and throw a socket exception immediately. It could be that the socket in your client application is taking time to detect socket closed event and hence exception throwing could have been delayed. It might be worth checking communication settings in JBoss server.

Comment: Where can I check that setting?